# Angular Ts [Primeng] How can i make this p-calendar not auto close after click

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

When click on button it opens up the time only p-calendar is expected but the issue here right now is when i click on increasing the time or decreasing it, this will cause the issue of auto close per click. Anyone that is able to help for this issue?
i also tried using autoclose='false' but it seems like not working

**Angular Version**: 9.1.3
**Node**: 12.21.0
**Primeng version**: 9.0.5

```
           <button
            type="button"
            [ngbPopover]="buttonContent"
            class="btn-date"
            (onSelect)="onInput()"
            placement="bottom"
            autoClose="false">
            <i class="spark-icon icon clipboard-text regular text-dark"></i>
          </button>
          
            <ng-template #buttonContent> 
            <div> 
                `<p-calendar [inline]="true" [showTime]="true" timeOnly="true" [(ngModel)]="endSelectedTime"></p-calendar> `
            </div> 
            </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it [here](https://primeng.org/calendar#api.calendar.props.hideOnDateTimeSelect)

Basically you can use the `[hideOnDateTimeSelect]="false"` attribute.
(And yes it is compatible with your primeng version.)